# Need to improve my db-syntax

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access

Overview: this is a code where a student can sign up for courses he want to read. **He should only be accepted into one course, not more**(*this is where I got problem with*). Although the student can search up to 3 courses at same time by priority selection 1-3.

If a courses is full then students get a queue-index, starting from 1 and up. Once there's a free spot in the course(*that's where this syntax below is being used, looping for each free spot in a course*), the student with queue-index 1 hit 0 and he's accepted into the course.

```
  cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [Register]  
                     SET QueueIndex = QueueIndex - 1,  
                     Accepted = IIF(QueueIndex = 1, 1, 0)  
                     WHERE QueueIndex > 0 AND CID = @cid;";
```

However I don't know how to improve this syntax and implement a checker if that student is already accepted. If he already is, then he should be NOT be accepted(*and set his queue-index to 0 so he's no longer in queue, and accepted is still false*) and check for the next student instead. I don't know how to improve this syntax.

In the db-table, I'm **using CID(course ID)**, **SID(student ID)**, **Accepted(bool)**, Selection(for 1-3 course choices, *not important here*),  **QueueIndex(int)**

I would like to implement some kind of.. If that current student with QueueIndex = 1, AND if any of his/SID choices/selections is Accepted = true  THEN QueueIndex = 0 and Accepted = false, so that current choice is no longer relevant since he's already accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it something like the following you are looking for?

```
UPDATE Register
SET QueueIndex=QueueIndex-1, Accepted=0
WHERE QueueIndex>0 
AND Accepted<>0
AND CID=@CID
```

If yes that seems problematic to me since now the accepted field is updated to false but that student has been registered already once and in the third attempt the where clause will be met accepting the student. if that's the case additional fields should be added to cover all possible scenarios. I would suggest to take a step back from the keyboard, get pen and paper and get your logic right. It will save you a lot of time. IF that is not the case ignore everything of the above up to pen and paper part!

Comment: Hi sorry for late response, is there anyway to add something like `(AND if (StudentID with QueueIndex= 1 have any (accepted=true) choices/CourseID) = false )` in `WHERE`? Like another syntax in WHERE part or something

Comment: If I get it right again that is still problematic. You have to keep track of all the students that have been accepted once already. Otherwise you lose that information whenever an update occur. Add another column or table for that. e.g. boolean field " Registered"